# Django base.html extension convention

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

With newer version of `Django`, it is recommended that staticfiles and templates be kept inside a directory named by the app name. For e.g. with older versions of `Django`, an app's structure looked something like this:

```
app
├── admin.py
├── __init__.py
├── models.py
├── static
│   └── design.css
├── templates
│   ├── base.html
│   └── index.html
├── tests.py
└── views.py
```

whereas with newer versions, the recommended structure is as following:

```
app
├── admin.py
├── __init__.py
├── models.py
├── static
│   └── app
│       └── design.css
├── templates
│   └── app
│       ├── base.html
│       └── index.html
├── tests.py
└── views.py
```

Now, how should I access staticfiles and templates in an app's view as per the newer app layout? That is, while accessing a template name in a view, is it a good idea to hardcode the app's name?

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', {})
```

Similarly, in the template `index.html` that extends `base.html`, it needs to be referenced as follows:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
```

Again, this involves hardcoding app's name in the template. Is it a good idea? If I decide to rename the app, I would need to make changes in so many files.

Or, am I missing any setting that would allow me to refer `base.html` as

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

in my templates, while avoiding to mention the app name?

Comment: awesome.. i never knew 'extends' and 'include' existed..

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with newer or older versions of django, this has to do with the fact that the `collectstatic` command will overwrite files of similar names; adding your app name creates a "namespace" for your static files.

You should only do this for static files, templates should go in a master "templates" directory for your application; and of course if you have templates that do not belong to an application, they should go in a separate directory (which is added to `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in `settings.py`).

Templates are loaded by [`TEMPLATE_LOADERS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#template-loaders) setting; and the defaults are to search the file system by going through the directories in `TEMPLATE_DIRS` and then search in any `template` directory for installed apps - which are searched in the order they are listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

The first template that matches the requested one will be used.  This makes it easy to ship default templates with your application, and then allow the end user to customize them; by creating a template with the same name and putting it in a directory listed in `TEMPLATE_DIRS`.

To avoid any possible clashes, it is best to add your app name to the template itself; so if you have `index.html` and your app is called `foo`, change the template to `foo_index.html` (as the default).

Comment: @BurhanKahlid: I get your point about static files and having to create a separate "namespace" for templates of each app, to avoid template name clashes. One way is to add app name in the template name, as you suggested. Another is to create a directory by the app name under master templates directory of the app. Later seems to be the convention. Have a look at the popular `django-registration` app. They seem to follow the later convention. However in each of their templates, they have mentioned `{% extend "base.html "%}`. Would say then, this is a bad practice on behalf of such a popular app?

Comment: `django-registration` app is here: https://github.com/macropin/django-registration

Comment: As long as you can prevent namespace clashes, use whatever suits you. Whenever I need to know how to best do something, I see how django does it (as all contrib apps are django apps) and I follow that convention. Specifically for your example, the templates are extending the [base template](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/blob/master/test_app/templates/base.html) that is provided with their sample app.

Answer (score 0):

I think hardcoding the app's name in the templates is a good idea as you might have several apps that have templates with the same name. If you just put the template's name, Django will take the first template with that name (which might be wrong in case you have several templates with same name).

Comment: Is it not possible to have settings in such a way that Django gives app's `base.html` preference above say, global or any other app's `base.html` and still not to have to hardcode the app's name?

Comment: I don't think you can do that on templates. On the views you can always set the app's name as global and then write the template as `appname + "/base.html"`